# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.moveStack(com.android.server.wm.TaskStack, boolean)'

Tags: android

Getting this issue while starting an activity on 7.1.1

```
Handler().postDelayed {

Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

}
```

Stack trace:
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1690)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3254)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1584)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4234)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4192)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4535)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4503)
at com.thepediatricnetwork.doctorapp.activities.SplashActivity$6.run(SplashActivity.java:233)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6339)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945)

Comment: This was only logged in Panasonic device OS 7.* You can ignore this issue as crash frequency and count would be low.